# How to disable Host Key Checking check on git over ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, git

When I want to execute `git clone git@github.com:Company/Repo` I see this message for the first time after installing a new linux instance:

```
Cloning into 'Repo'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

And when I answer `yes` I get this message:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
```

I know this is for security. But since we are creating some mini-tools for our company, we prefer to disable this feature for our development environment.

We want it to be disabled, so that our bash scripts would work even the first time on a new installation.

How can we do that?

P.S. Please don't advice on security. We know the risks and we're ready to take it.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you connect to the git main machine via the SSH protocol. In fact, it is a common practice with SSH.

What it does is add the host key of the computer to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, effectively, for security.

The best option is to add the computer settings in the `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host 172.16.0.1
    User git
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    ...
```

But you should do it for each client and it may not be the most appropriate for your case.

So, what you understand that it would be more appropriate is to change the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable to tell git to ignore the host key checking when connecting by SSH, in such a way that:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" git clone git@github.com:Company/Repo
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy and safe solution is not to disable key checking but rather to add the github key. Just add to your scripts:

```bash
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

If needed, have the scripts `mkdir ~/.ssh`.

If `ssh-keyscan` is not available - `apt install` either `ssh` or `openssh-client` (the latter is lighter and sufficient if you need only ssh-keyscan).